# How to search through element hidden by a toggled tab with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract and print the text contents of all td tags from a url which possesses multiple tabs that display certain elements of the page and hide the contents of all of the other tabs when clicked (https://www.encodeproject.org/experiments/ENCSR000EEC/). Specifically, I am trying to extract all of the td tags from the "File Details" tab (the complete list of tabs, seen in the middle of the page, is: "Genome Browser", "Association Graph", and "File Details"). Currently, the only td tags I am able to extract are from a section above the div with the tabs which also possesses td tags. The only tab that contains td tags is "File Details." How can I access the hidden contents within the "File Details" tab? Current code:

```
def test_select_files(url):
    texts = []
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    td_tags = soup.findAll('td')
    for tag in td_tags: 
        print(tag.text.strip())

test_select_files('https://www.encodeproject.org/experiments/ENCSR000EEC/')
```

desired output (directly from the url):

```
bed narrowPeak  
bigBed narrowPeak   
bigWig  
bed idr_ranked_peak 
bed narrowPeak  
...
```

Comment: Example output ?

Comment: Just added to the question above!

Comment: this is your current output, I meant to ask about an example of expected output!

Comment: oh, woops, my bad! just fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get all of the information you need from the JSON that is returned inside the HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.encodeproject.org/experiments/ENCSR000EEC/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
json_data = soup.find('script', type='application/json').string
data = json.loads(json_data)    

for file in data['files']:
    print(f"{file['accession']}  {file['file_format']:10}  {file['output_type']}")
```

This would give you output starting:

```
ENCFF000XTK  bam         alignments
ENCFF000XTL  bam         alignments
ENCFF000XTM  bigBed      peaks
ENCFF000XTP  bigWig      signal
ENCFF000XTZ  fastq       reads
ENCFF000XUA  fastq       reads
ENCFF001VKJ  bed         peaks
ENCFF002CUG  bed         optimal IDR thresholded peaks
ENCFF715UNN  bigBed      optimal IDR thresholded peaks
ENCFF836BQL  bam         unfiltered alignments
```

I suggest you `print(data)` to understand what other information is available for each file.

Comment: I'll give it a try. You're amazing, thank you so much!